# Install issue pyCuda on Python 3.4, windows 10, Visual Studio 17, CUda 8.061

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.4

So simply running the installers for Visual Studio, CUDA and doing a cheeky pip install pycuda led to an epic fail - hence this post. Has anyone used this combination recently - most posts appear to be about Visual Studio 12 and CUDA 7.5 . Any hint on known compatibility issues or instructions to have this installed would be most helpful.
As pointed out below - this apparently wont work.

Also - I realized I have an AMD radeon - so opencl is the only real option - Will update if this installs smoothly.

Comment: Thanks -how about opencl-  pyopencl?